# Is there an arrayformula to fill all blank cells in a column with the content from the cell above?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-vlookup

In the following Google sheet:

```
  A          B
 ------------------------
1| Tom     | something  |
2|         | something  |
3| John    | something  |
4| Lana    | something  |
5|         | something  |
6|         | something  |
7| Jason   | something  |
 ------------------------
```

I want an array formula applied to column A which will automatically fill any blanks with the last data in the cell above (or above that, if there are multiple blanks).

The result should look like this:

```
  A          B
 ------------------------
1| Tom     | something  |
2| Tom     | something  |
3| John    | something  |
4| Lana    | something  |
5| Lana    | something  |
6| Lana    | something  |
7| Jason   | something  |
 ------------------------
```

As the sheet can be massive, applying the formula to each cell is not practical.

If I paste the formula `=if(ISBLANK(A2), A1)` into the blanks manually it will fill them, but dragging said formula over a whole column will not work.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646168/fill-empty-cells-with-the-same-value-as-previous-cell-in-google-sheet-array-for

Comment: And this: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/fill-blank-cells-with-the-values-above/

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do it with vlookup, by creating an array that includes a row number and using the inexact lookup form of vlookup so that it finds the previous row that contains text:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({vlookup(row(A:A),{if(A:A<>"",row(A:A)),A:A},2),B:B},"select Col1,Col2 where Col2 is not null"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That solution might help from this source:

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/fill-blank-cells-with-the-values-above/

The advantage it doesn't add extra rows at the tail end of the column.

```
= scan(0, indirect("B2:B" & reduce(0, B: B, lambda(a, v, (
  if (v = "", v & a, row(v)))))), lambda(a, v,
  if (v = "", a, v)))
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to achieve this goal would be to create a new column, and use the formula `=IF(ISBLANK($A2), $B1, $A2)` from B2 down. I think that what you meant was that you can't simply replace the column in place, correct? This would solve it in that case, but it is not a single arrayformula. If you are worried about inserting the formula into all rows, try selecting the first cell, CTRL+SHIFT+Down arrow key to select the full range, and CTRL+ENTER to paste the formula.

If you truly need an arrayformula, one would hope that `=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A), B1:B, A2:A))` or the like would work, but unfortunately Sheets does not iterate over the results of this formula so that it does. Other functions (such as vlookup) *do* work properly, but I'm not sure how to compose a formula to achieve what you're looking to do here using those.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your Q in one word "NO" (though slightly simplistic).

An approach that might suit is to filter ColumnA to select `(Blanks)` only and in the first blank cell (in your case A2) enter:

```
=A1
```

where the `1` is the number of the row immediately above the formula cell.

Copy down to suit and Edit > Copy > Edit > Paste special > Paste values only, then take off the filter.