# Filtering date in google sheets and cells under it

Tags: google-sheets

I want to filter a date and get the cells under it and it ends before it reaches another date.

Not familiar with filtering on excel where it only gets the date but not the cells under the rows on it.
[From this (without filtering)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncyrq.png) to [this (with filtering)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trhW5.png)

Comment: Your question title refers to "google sheets", you tagged "google-sheets" but your question refers to "excel". A solution for one does not necessarily apply to the other. Please advise which spreadsheet you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an arrayformula to fill all blank cells in a column with the content from the cell above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860898/is-there-an-arrayformula-to-fill-all-blank-cells-in-a-column-with-the-content-fr)